# Comprehensive list of 'missing' features in Blender 2.8?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am considering moving from 2.79b to 2.8, but I am still unclear of what 2.8 doesn't yet have. Is there a list of all the features it lacks (in comparison to 2.79x).

All I have so far mostly is this from 2018.

> Currently, a few areas area still being completed:
>
> - Stable and well documented Python API for add-ons developers.
> - User interface for Collections in the 3D viewport.
> - Keymap for left-click select that works well with the new tool system, and a new keymap compatible with other software.
> - Making image empty objects a fully-featured replacement for background images.
> - Restore support for all the physics systems within the new dependency graph.
> - New subdivision surface and multi-resolution modifier implementations based on Pixar’s OpenSubiv.

P.S. also interested in features missing from Animation Nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.80 has solved all of these aspects.

> Stable and well documented Python API for add-ons developers.

The Python API for 2.80 is documented in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/index.html). The API was completed on [24th of May, 2019](https://code.blender.org/2019/05/user-interface-and-api-freeze/). It's stable in the sense that there are no major changes between 2.8x releases at the time of writing. Add-ons written for 2.80 continue to work in 2.81 and 2.82.

> User interface for Collections in the 3D viewport.

I assume this refers to the updated [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/outliner.html). This has been completed, collections and view layer replace the old render layer system from 2.79. The concept is explained in the [View Layers and Collections](https://code.blender.org/2017/09/view-layers-and-collections/) post by Dalai Felinto on the developer blog.

> Keymap for left-click select that works well with the new tool system, and a new keymap compatible with other software.

The new keymap system allows you to choose between left- and right-click select. You can create completely customized keymaps. There is an *Industry Compatible* keymap included in Blender which may help professionals to transition from other 3D software.

[image]

> Making image empty objects a fully-featured replacement for background images.

There are two image object types, the *Reference* and *Background* objects. Both are based on empties. This is only for images that do not appear in the render though. If you want your image to appear in the render, then the *Image as Planes* add-on is still quite useful.

[image]

> Restore support for all the physics systems within the new dependency graph.

The major dependency graph changes have been completed. Some technical information about the design can be found in the wiki article [Blender 2.8: Dependency Graph](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Depsgraph).

> New subdivision surface and multi-resolution modifier implementations based on Pixar’s OpenSubiv.

The modifiers now use OpenSubdiv which has been integrated by Sergey Sharybin.

Comment: Thanks, can I conclude then that what I posted **was** the comprehensive list of missing features? If so your answer has essentially cleared it all up.

Comment: The points you've mentioned were at some point tasks on the roadmap of 2.80 during the development. It's by no means a complete list. However it wasn't anything that was ever missing from the release version of 2.80. So it depends what you intend to compare. BTW in case that wasn't clear BGE and Blender Internal have been removed, the latter has been replaced by Eevee.

Comment: Noted that the list was not comprehensive. My concerns where that after having used 2.7x to learn, (and still learning) that 2.8x could potentially throw a spanner in the works by the omission something. NB I don't mean changes or replacements, for instance BGE to Eevee.

Answer (score 1):

2.81 was just released, it is worth taking a look at, it solves quite a few issues and adds a load of new stuff.

In the meantime I think you can strike these off your list.

- <strike>Keymap for left-click select that works well with the new tool system, and a new keymap compatible with other software.</strike>
- <strike>Making image empty objects a fully-featured replacement for background images.</strike>

If you can wait until February 2020, [v2.82](https://developer.blender.org/project/view/89/) will have some major performance improvements, in particular for Windows users who have had some issues.

Comment: OK, TBH it didn't seem the improvements that are coming ever really benefit me, my core interest is Motion Graphics, and that be frank even as a fan of blender it feels so very neglected. Animation Nodes is powerful but man the complexity and maths needed is terrifying. And let's not speak of the text support. Anyway I digress.

Comment: 2D or 3D? The improvements to grease pencil have been amazing!  Yes text is always being asked about.

Comment: Predominantly 2d but not just, I mean the type of mo graphics C4D's Mograph excels at. My fingers are often figuratively crossed for more in this area but usually it's modeling features and other 3d areas of interest. Grease pencil is great but again it's a different field/area imo

Comment: Unfortunately Animation Nodes seems to be broken on 2.8x, at least as far as I can tell.  Yes, anything node based is math-friendly, not creator friendly.

Comment: That's helpful to know, but if so not the best news TBH.

Comment: Might work on windows, I've only tested the linux package, I'm going to try and build from source.

Comment: Thanks, I'm Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I have kept *both* 2.79 and 2.8 on my computer. I simply changed the folder name on the former so not to have the latter overwriting the other. 
My ***reasons*** for keeping 2.79: one, I download creators' past works and I like viewing them in 2.79; two, some custom addons are not updated for 2.8; three, I watch old tutorials and vlogs.

Comment: OK but how do you manage the two different versions of Python on the same device? (I am Mac if it matters).

Comment: I have no problem with the two versions. I am not too familiar with Python, though I am trying to learn it. Tomorrow, if you are interested, I will make a video of my desktop & folders and post it in re-edit.

Comment: Yes. Very much interested.

Comment: @PeterAskins I will get back to you either tomorrow our Monday, when I open PC in another location. I will screencast everything.